# Properly Writing Object Oriented Code in java for a stack

Tags: java, stack, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to write code in a way that it is object oriented. In this particular case I want to keep track of the minimum value of my stack in O(1) time. I know how to do it, the idea of it, well my idea of it, which is to have another stack that keeps track of the minimum value for every push and pop.

I've nested every class inside of the program class which is called **minStack**, which doesn't seem like the right thing to do however when I create a instance of minStack and call its variables it works out fine for a regular stack. I created a class that **extends** a **Stack** called **StackWithMin** but I don't know how to call its values. Should I create a new instance of a StackWithMin? If so how would i do it? I did it at the end of the code above the main function, but peek() always returns null

```
class minStack {

public class Stack {

    Node top;
    Object min = null;

    Object pop() {
        if(top != null) {
            Object item = top.getData();
            top = top.getNext();
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

    void push(Object item) {
        if(min == null) {
            min = item;
        }
        if((int)item < (int)min) {
            min = item;
        }
        Node pushed = new Node(item, top);
        top = pushed;
    }

    Object peek() {
        if(top == null) {
            //System.out.println("Its null or stack is empty");
            return null;
        }   
        return top.getData();
    }

    Object minimumValue() {
        if(min == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (int)min;
    }
}

public class Node {
    Object data;
    Node next;

    public Node(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(Object data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setData(Object d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

public class StackWithMin extends Stack {
    Stack s2;

    public StackWithMin() {
        s2 = new Stack();
    }

    public void push(Object value) {
        if((int)value <= (int)min()) {
            s2.push(value);
        }
        super.push(value);
    }

    public Object pop() {
        Object value = super.pop();
        if((int)value == (int)min()) {
            s2.pop();
        }
        return value;
    }

    public Object min() {
        if(s2.top == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return s2.peek();
        }
    }
}

Stack testStack = new Stack();
StackWithMin stackMin = new StackWithMin();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    minStack mStack = new minStack();
    //StackWithMin stackMin = new StackWithMin();
    mStack.testStack.push(3);
    mStack.testStack.push(5);
    mStack.testStack.push(2);
    mStack.stackMin.push(2);
    mStack.stackMin.push(4);
    mStack.stackMin.push(1);
    System.out.println(mStack.testStack.peek());
    System.out.println(mStack.stackMin.peek());
    mStack.testStack.pop();


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create generic interface `Stack` like this one

```
interface Stack<T> {

    void push(T item);

    T pop();

    T peek();
}
```

> Generics add stability to your code by making more of your bugs
>   detectable at compile time.

See more about generics [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Then implement this interface in a common way. All implementation details will be hidden inside of this class (your `Node` class for example). Here is the code (it is just to show the idea, if you want to use it you need to improve it with exception handling for example). Note that class `Node` is now also generic.

```
class SimpleStack<T> implements Stack<T> {

    private class Node<T> { ... }

    private Node<T> root = null;

    public void push(T item) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node<T>(item);
        } else {
            Node<T> node = new Node<T>(item, root);
            root = node;
        }
    }

    public T pop() {
        if (root != null) {
            T data = root.getData();
            root = root.getNext();
            return data;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public T peek() {
        if (root != null) {
            return root.getData();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we get to the part with stored minimum value. We can extend our `SimpleStack` class and add field with another `SimpleStack`. However I think this is better to make another implementation of the `Stack` and store two stacks for values and for minimums. The example is below. I have generalize the class that now uses `Comparator` to compare object, so you can use any other object types.

```
class StackWithComparator<T> implements Stack<T> {

    private Comparator<T> comparator;
    private SimpleStack<T> mins = new SimpleStack<>();
    private SimpleStack<T> data = new SimpleStack<>();

    public StackWithComparator(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public void push(T item) {
        data.push(item);
        if (mins.peek() == null || comparator.compare(mins.peek(), item) >= 0) {
            mins.push(item);
        } else {
            mins.push(mins.peek());
        }
    }

    public T pop() {
        mins.pop();
        return data.pop();
    } 

    public T peek() {
        return data.peek();
    }

    public T min() {
        return mins.peek();
    }
}
```

Now you can use both implementations like so

```
SimpleStack<Integer> s1 = new SimpleStack<>();
s1.push(1);
s1.push(2);
s1.push(3);

System.out.println(s1.pop()); // print 3
System.out.println(s1.pop()); // print 2
System.out.println(s1.pop()); // print 1

StackWithComparator<Integer> s2 = new StackWithComparator<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});
s2.push(1);
s2.push(2);
s2.push(3);
s2.push(0);
s2.push(4);

System.out.println(s2.min() + " " + s2.pop()); // print 0 4
System.out.println(s2.min() + " " + s2.pop()); // print 0 0
System.out.println(s2.min() + " " + s2.pop()); // print 1 3
System.out.println(s2.min() + " " + s2.pop()); // print 1 2
System.out.println(s2.min() + " " + s2.pop()); // print 1 1
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you, the relative interface for T, means we can obstaniate it with any kind of data type, which is cool. Thanks man.